# Mongo continues to insert documents, slowly, long after script is quit

Tags: mongodb

Do I have a zombie somewhere?

My script finished inserting a massive amount of new data.

However, the server continues with high lock rates and slowly inserting new records. It's been about an hour since the script that did the inserts finished, and the documents are still trickling in.

Where are these coming from and how to I purge the queue? (I refactored the code to use an index and want to redo the process to avoid the 100-200% lock rate)

Comment: Does your script use unacknowledged writes when inserting?  If so, the actual inserts may take place after your script completes.

Comment: Use db.currentOp() to check what op is executing. Unsafe mode write may lead to this condition.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of following scenarios,

***1..Throughput bound Disk IO***

One can look into following metrics using "mongostat" and "MongoDB Management Service":

- Average Flush time (how long MongoDB's periodic sync to disk is taking)
- IOStats in the hardware tab (look specifically IOWait)

Since the Disk IO is slower than CPU processing time, all the inserts get queued up, and this can continue for longer duration, one can check the server status using db.serverStatus() and look into "globalLock"(as Write acquires global lock) field for "currrentQueue" associated with the lock, to see number of writers in queue.

***2..Another possible cause could be Managed Sharded Cluster Balancer has been put in On Status(which is by Default On)***

If you have been working on clustered environment, whenever write operation starts Balancer automatically gets ON, in-order to keep the cluster in balanced state, which can continue moving chunks from one shard to another even after completion of your scripts. In such a case I would rather suggest to keep the balancer off while having bulk load, in such a case all your documents goes to single shard, but balancer can be kicked on at any downtime.

***3..Write Concern*** 
This may also contribute to problem slightly, if they are set to Replica Acknowledged or Acknowledged mode, it depends on you, based on your type of data, to decide on these concerns.